# Is there a way to figure out the smallest width a table column will be when the window is shrunk?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to link two tables so that they have the same column widths. When a column reaches it's minimum size, I want to set the min-size property of of the corresponding column in my other table. I cannot find a good solution to this problem.

I have tried to compare the column widths of the upper and lower tables' columns to look for when they become unsynchronized. However, due to what I believe are rounding differences between the column widths, the min-width property is being set prematurely. This approach does not seem to be sufficient so I need another way to determine when a table column will not get any smaller.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: @Kosh https://jsfiddle.net/bsoccer/w2yqax9b/10/ if the DOM gets too small, the tables get unsynchronized, but if the min width is set, they will remain together. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.